# how to get the sql server listener name

Tags: sql-server, powershell, listener, cluster-computing

on a Failover Cluster (no AVG), two nodes, I've got two SQL Instances registered with Logical names the differ from the Computer Name. I Need to get the listener (Logical) SQL Name to connect to an instance to collect some inventory data.

I use the get-cluster command:

```
import-module failoverclusters

$Clusters = Get-Cluster 
foreach ($Cluster in $Clusters)
{
  #write-host $Cluster.Name 
  try
  {
      $ClusterResources = Get-ClusterResource -Cluster $Cluster 

      foreach($Resource in $ClusterResources)
      {
      $Resource
      }
   }
   catch [System.Exception]
   {
        write-host "!An error occurred!"
   }
   write-host  ""
}
```

I get:

> ```
> Name                     State   Group                ResourceType 
> ----                     -----   -----                ------------
> SQL IP Address 1 (nXXX)  Online  SQL Server (M_REP1)  IP Address
> SQL IP Address 1 (nYYY)  Online  SQL Server (M_REP2)  IP Address
> ```

`SQL IP Address 1(nXXX)` is the listener, `SQL SERVER (M_REP1)` the instance.
Do I have work on the string to get: `nXXX\M_REP1` or is there another way

Comment: `$Resource.Name`

Comment: Kumar, as I said, $Resource.Name gives me: SQL IP Address 1 (n2xxxx), means the listener I Need is: n2xxxx, so I have cut the string and get what I have in Parentheses. And I asked for the "better" way..

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT AGS.name  AS AGName, 
     HAGS.primary_replica AS PrimaryInstance 
 FROM   sys.dm_hadr_availability_group_states HAGS 
 INNER JOIN sys.availability_groups AGS 
 ON HAGS.group_id = AGS.group_id
```

Comment: While it’s acceptable to provide code-only answers, it’s often more useful for the community if you can also provide an explanation of the code and help people understand _why_ it addresses the problem. That can reduce the number of follow-up questions, and  help new developers understand the underlying concepts. Would you mind updating your question with additional detail?

Comment: I am no developer; I have learnt a lot by just finding code on here and teaking it to meet my needs